# Cannot build file on Editorial Manager

Tags: compiling

I am submitting a manuscript through [Editorial Manager](https://www.editorialmanager.com/). I am getting this error. The manuscript successfully compiles on my local computer and also on [WriteLatex](http://www.writelatex.com) which I used for editing. As I am new to Latex, I don't know how to fix this. This is compiled on the server side, so I cannot modify the installation folder. The problem is that I don't even know which line is causing the error in my manuscript file. Could someone please help me? The deadline for submission is today.

It says
 `I can't find file 'tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex'... l.32 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}` but I don't even declare that as a package. Is it one of the packages I use that imports that? How do I know which one? These are my imports:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

The log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX) (format=pdflatex 2013.9.11) 
31 DEC 2013 08:24 
entering extended mode 
 restricted \write18 enabled. 
 %&-line parsing enabled. 
**main.tex 
(./main.tex 
LaTeX2e  
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded. 

LaTeX Warning: File `example.eps' already exists on the system. 
 Not generating it from this source. 

(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty 
Package: fix-cm 2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def 
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file 
)) (c:/TeXLive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/latex/aries/svjour3.cls 
Document Class: svjour3 2010/11/25 v3.3 
LaTeX document class for Springer journals 
Class Springer-SVJour3 Info: extra/valid Springer sub-package (-> *.clo) 
(Springer-SVJour3) not found in option list of \documentclass 
(Springer-SVJour3) - autoactivating "global" style. 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/../texmf-local/tex/latex/aries/svglov3.clo 
File: svglov3.clo 2009/12/18 v3.2 style option for standardised journals 
SVJour Class option: svglov3.clo for standardised journals 
) 
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 147. 
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 148. 
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 149. 
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 150. 
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 151. 
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 152. 
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 153. 
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 154. 
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 155. 
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 156. 
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 157. 
\logodepth=\dimen102 
\headerboxheight=\dimen103 
\betweenumberspace=\dimen104 
\aftertext=\dimen105 
\headlineindent=\dimen106 
\c@inst=\count79 
\c@auth=\count80 
\instindent=\dimen107 
\authrun=\box26 
\authorrunning=\toks14 
\titrun=\box27 
\titlerunning=\toks15 
\combirun=\box28 
\c@lastpage=\count81 
Manuscript
Click here to download Manuscript: main.tex 
Click here to view linked References
\rubricwidth=\dimen108 
\c@section=\count82 
\c@subsection=\count83 
\c@subsubsection=\count84 
\c@paragraph=\count85 
\c@subparagraph=\count86 
\spthmsep=\dimen109 
\c@theorem=\count87 
\c@case=\count88 
\c@conjecture=\count89 
\c@corollary=\count90 
\c@definition=\count91 
\c@example=\count92 
\c@exercise=\count93 
\c@lemma=\count94 
\c@note=\count95 
\c@problem=\count96 
\c@property=\count97 
\c@proposition=\count98 
\c@question=\count99 
\c@solution=\count100 
\c@remark=\count101 
\c@figure=\count102 
\c@table=\count103 
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41 
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42 
\figcapgap=\dimen110 
\tabcapgap=\dimen111 
\figgap=\dimen112 
\bibindent=\dimen113 
\@tempcntc=\count104 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty 
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO) 
\bibhang=\skip43 
\bibsep=\skip44 
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694. 
\c@NAT@ctr=\count105 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty 
Package: todonotes 2012/07/25 .dtx Todonotes source and documentation. 
Package: todonotes 2012/07/25 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty 
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC) 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty 
Package: xkeyval 2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex 
\XKV@toks=\toks16 
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17 
\XKV@depth=\count106 
File: xkeyval.tex 2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))) (c:/TeXLive/2013/ 
texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty 
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg 
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive 
) 
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225. 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def 
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty 
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO) 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty 
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO) 
) 
\Gread@gobject=\count107 
) 
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337. 
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341. 
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353. 
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355. 
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356. 
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357. 
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358. 
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359. 
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360. 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (c:/TeXLive/ 
2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/te 
x/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/ut 
ilities/pgfutil-common.tex 
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks18 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def 
\pgfutil@abb=\box29 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty 
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS) 
)) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex 
Package: pgfrcs 2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24) 
)) 
Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (c:/TeXLive/20 
13/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty 
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty 
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty 
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC) 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg 
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live 
) 
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91. 
) 
\Gin@req@height=\dimen114 
\Gin@req@width=\dimen115 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (c:/TeXLive/ 
2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex 
Package: pgfsys 2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex 
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks19 
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks20 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex 
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks21 
)) 
\pgf@x=\dimen116 
\pgf@y=\dimen117 
\pgf@xa=\dimen118 
\pgf@ya=\dimen119 
\pgf@xb=\dimen120 
\pgf@yb=\dimen121 
\pgf@xc=\dimen122 
\pgf@yc=\dimen123 
\w@pgf@writea=\write3 
\r@pgf@reada=\read1 
\c@pgf@counta=\count108 
\c@pgf@countb=\count109 
\c@pgf@countc=\count110 
\c@pgf@countd=\count111 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg 
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14 (rcs-revision 1.7) 
) 
Package pgfsys Info: Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def on input line 900. 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def 
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2009/05/22 (rcs-revision 1.26) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def 
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2008/05/19 (rcs-revision 1.10) 
))) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2008/07/18 (rcs-revision 1.7) 
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count112 
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count113 
) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16 (rcs-revision 1.4) 
)) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex 
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (c:/TeXLive/2 
013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf 
-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/te 
x/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex 
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen124 
\pgfmath@count=\count114 
\pgfmath@box=\box30 
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22 
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23 
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te 
x) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric 
.code.tex) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t 
ex) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co 
de.tex) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex 
) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te 
x) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex 
))) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex 
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count115 
)) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.te 
x 
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2010/04/09 (rcs-revision 1.20) 
\pgf@picminx=\dimen125 
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen126 
\pgf@picminy=\dimen127 
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen128 
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen129 
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen130 
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen131 
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen132 
\pgf@xx=\dimen133 
\pgf@xy=\dimen134 
\pgf@yx=\dimen135 
\pgf@yy=\dimen136 
\pgf@zx=\dimen137 
\pgf@zy=\dimen138 
) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod 
e.tex 
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2010/08/03 (rcs-revision 1.24) 
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen139 
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen140 
) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te 
x 
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2008/04/22 (rcs-revision 1.12) 
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen141 
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen142 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex 
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2010/09/08 (rcs-revision 1.34) 
\pgfpic=\box31 
\pgf@hbox=\box32 
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box33 
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count116 
) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code 
.tex 
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2008/04/22 (rcs-revision 1.9) 
\pgflinewidth=\dimen143 
) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c 
ode.tex 
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2009/06/10 (rcs-revision 1.11) 
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen144 
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen145 
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen146 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex 
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09 (rcs-revision 1.3) 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.te 
x 
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11 (rcs-revision 1.2) 
) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co 
de.tex 
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2008/10/09 (rcs-revision 1.8) 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex 
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2008/04/23 (rcs-revision 1.11) 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex 
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2008/11/23 (rcs-revision 1.13) 
\pgf@max=\dimen147 
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count117 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex 
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2010/03/25 (rcs-revision 1.16) 

(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2010/09/01 (rcs-revision 1.17) 
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box34 
)) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.te 
x 
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2010/08/27 (rcs-revision 1.2) 
) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code 
.tex 
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2008/01/17 (rcs-revision 1.2) 
) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2009/07/02 (rcs-revision 1.3) 
))) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.te 
x 
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2010/09/09 (rcs-revision 1.13) 
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box35 
) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2010/10/22 (rcs-revision 1.8) 
) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st 
y 
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7) 
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen148 
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen149 
) 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st 
y 
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1) 
)) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (c:/TeXLive/2 
013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/ 
tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/ge 
neric/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex 
Package: pgffor 2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18) 
\pgffor@iter=\dimen150 
\pgffor@skip=\dimen151 
\pgffor@stack=\toks25 
\pgffor@toks=\toks26 
)) (c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex 
Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76) 

(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co 
de.tex 
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2010/05/31 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.15) 
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count118 
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen152 
) 
\tikz@lastx=\dimen153 
\tikz@lasty=\dimen154 
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen155 
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen156 
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen157 
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen158 
\tikz@figbox=\box36 
\tikz@tempbox=\box37 
\tikztreelevel=\count119 
\tikznumberofchildren=\count120 
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count121 
\tikz@fig@count=\count122 
(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2010/08/24 (rcs-revision 1.4) 
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count123 
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count124 
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count125 
) 
\tikz@expandcount=\count126 

(c:/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli 
brarytopaths.code.tex 
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2) 
))) 
! I can't find file `tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex'. 
 ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
 \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz... 
l.32 \usetikzlibrary{positioning} 

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to exit) 
Please type another input file name 
! Emergency stop.
```

Comment: The problem is with `todonotes`, I believe. They seem to have an outdated version of the TikZ/PGF suite.

Answer (score 5):

Too late for your submission, but I just ran into the very same issue with editorial manager. I had tikz code in my paper and I needed it to compile. My fix was uploading `tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex` and `tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex` from TeX Live additionally to my manuscript. The files are available in the [svn repository of TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/). Maybe that is helpful for someone else.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The files are already included in recent TikZ/pgf version 3.0, and this can be installed by updating TeX Live.

Answer (score 2):

As egreg points out, the problem is in the package `todonotes`.
I had exactly the same problem and the solution was to comment out the line

```
\usepackage{todonotes}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I found an alternative solution. First, generate a pdf file from your tikz code through externalisation. See section 33 of the [manual](https://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf) for externalisation. Once you have your pdf files, you can replace your code with `\includegraphics[<options>]{filename.pdf}` of the `graphicx` package.

Comment: not the best solution. takes too much time for 30-40 figures.